# Lazy Loading in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have 10000 records in my Database and i want to show them in LongListSelector. I want to load first 20 records in LongListSelector first and when user scrolls to end of LongListSelector then want to add next 20 records in LongListSelector and so on, when user reaches the end of page then more data are loaded.
any one can tell me that how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could simply use the `LongListSelector.ItemRealized` and `LongListSelector.ItemunRealized` events to to trigger fetching of real data into the item `ViewModels`.

You could refer these:
[Does LongListSelector make Lazy Load for us?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304981/)

[Lazy Loading with LongListSelector in LayoutMode=Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766667/)